# Pass selected values out of HTML with JScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, parameter-passing

Kinda new to HTML and JS.  Am working on something for a lab computer.

I have cobbled together this code from a few SO sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361034/select-html-row-and-get-selected-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979931/obtain-field-td-values-by-clicking-on-table-row) and am coming up short.

**What I am tryin to do:**  Have my user select from various rows in a table.  The rows in those data are presented to user in a lower portion of the page for confirmation.  I think need to pass out those parameters to a larger method written in VBScript (for a Biomek liquid handler).

The variables I am passing are global variables in my main program but that program is not "seeing" the variable change by what row is selected.

No matter what I do I cannot get the variable out either A) at all or B) in a numeric form (I need it to be numeric).  I either get no global variable change or just a string being passed out.

I think once I identify the value that is selected by the operator and can pass that VALUE into something else I can pass out, but for now all I am able to assign is the string name of the variable and not the value behind it.

**Problematic Script:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
      table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
      }
  </style> 
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function showRow(row)
      {
      var x=row.cells;
     document.getElementById("Volume1").value = x[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("Volume2").value = x[1].innerHTML;
  }
  function ChangeColor(row, highLight)
  {
  if (highLight)
  {
    row.style.backgroundColor = '#dcfac9';
  }
  else
  {
    row.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="http://localhost">
  <table id="myTable" cellspacing="3"
      <thead>
          <tr>
        <th>Volume 1</th>
        <th>Volume 2</th>
      </tr>
      </thead> 
      <tbody> 
          <tr onclick="javascript:showRow(this);"
              onmouseover="javascript:ChangeColor(this, true);" 
              onmouseout="javascript:ChangeColor(this, false);" >
             <td>88.4</td>
             <td>100</td>
          </tr>
           <tr onclick="javascript:showRow(this);"
              onmouseover="javascript:ChangeColor(this, true);" 
              onmouseout="javascript:ChangeColor(this, false);" > 
             <td>22.8</td>
             <td>44</td>
          </tr> 
           <tr onclick="javascript:showRow(this);"
              onmouseover="javascript:ChangeColor(this, true);" 
              onmouseout="javascript:ChangeColor(this, false);" > 
             <td>73.2</td>
             <td>125</td>
          </tr> 
           <tr onclick="javascript:showRow(this);"
              onmouseover="javascript:ChangeColor(this, true);" 
              onmouseout="javascript:ChangeColor(this, false);" > 
            <td>13.64</td>
             <td>17</td>
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  Volume 1 is:<input type="text" id="Volume1" />
  <br>
  Volume 2 is:<input type="text" id="Volume2" />
  <br>
  <br><br><br>
  <INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submitButton__" VALUE="CONTINUE" />
  </FORM>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Previous Success:**
In the past I have been able to accomplish what I am attempting.  In the snippet below, I am successfully able to "see" the values for the variables "*user_NumberSamples*", *"user_Replicates*", and "*user_DiluteSample*" from my main program. So while this worked in the past my current usecase is a little different, as you'll see:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
<!-- ***** Put scripts for handling page elements here -->
</SCRIPT>
<BODY BGCOLOR="BlanchedAlmond">
<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="http://localhost">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">TEST METHOD</h1>
<TABLE BOARDER=1>
 <TR>
   <P><h3 style="text-align:center;">Please enter all of the required information</h3></TD>
 </P>
 <BR>
<p>
</p>
 <TR>
    <TR><strong>Enter the number of samples being tested:            </strong></TR>
    <TR><INPUT TYPE=text  NAME="user_NumberSamples"  SIZE=2 VALUE="48">
 </TR>
<br>
<br>
<p>
  <TR><strong>Please select the number of REPLICTES:          </strong><TR>
  <select name="user_Replicates" size="1">
   <option>3</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>1</option>
  </select></BR>
 <TR>
</TABLE>
<br>
<tr><strong>Perform a pre-dilution of Samples 1:10?:</strong></tr>
  <input type="radio" id="False" name="user_DiluteSample" value="False" checked>
  <label for="False">False</label>
  <input type="radio" id="True" name="user_DiluteSample" value="True">
  <label for="True">True</label><br>
<p>NOTE: Diluting samples will make all replicates come from the same dilution plate, i.e. technical replicates<p>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submitButton__" VALUE="Click To Continue">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've tried a lot of things that I can't really articulate, hours and hours of this so now its time to ask some experts.  Thanks!

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. What's wrong with the web page?

Comment: I need to get the data OUT of the HTML dialog/GUI and into another program so that I can use those data downstream after the user has selected the right row in the table. 
 The table contains the data I need downstream.  I am at a loss as to how to do that

Comment: Put two name attributes on the input fields. They are distinct. Submit. What happens?

Comment: You get sent to something like page.html?name1=value1&name2=value2.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Thanks for the hints but unfortunately I don't quite understand.  Could you please elaborate if you have time?  Thanks!  ELI5

Comment: Input fields should be `<input type="text" id="Volume1" name="Volume1" />` and `<input type="text" id="Volume2" name="Volume2" />`. Try it!

Comment: I guess you mean JavaScript and not JScript. JScript was a Microsoft-specific thing.

Comment: Have you considered doing this project as an HTA? That will give you more options for passing data to other programs. For example, you could run another script and pass data via command line parameters or pass data via a file or registry keys.

Comment: In JScript, window and document are undefined.